# Vue.js / Axios : How to return data from a complex Axios structure?

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, vue.js, axios

I'm working on a projet using Vue.js + typescript + axios, and i'm actually trying to create a complex ApiRequest. In other words, i don't want to do that :

```
data (){
    return {
        users:[]
    }
},

methods: {
    getUsers : function() {
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:9090/Users")
          .then(response => {
            this.users = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
    }
}
```

because is not enough maintenable in a big project.

Instead of that, i created an "ApiService.ts" file where i declared the GET function :

```
import axios from "axios";

import { ApiRequest } from "../models/api/ApiRequest";
import { HttpMethod } from "../enums/HttpMethod";

const httpClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:9090"
});

class ApiService {

    async get<T=any>(url: string): Promise<T>{
        return await this.perform<T>({
            method: HttpMethod.GET,
            url,
        });
    }


    private async perform<T = any>(request: ApiRequest): Promise<T> {
        try {
            const response =  await httpClient({
                method: request.method,
                url: request.url,
            });
            console.log(response.data)
            return response.data
        }   catch (error) {
            const message = error.response
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message;
    
            throw Error (message);   
        }
    }
}

export const apiService = new ApiService();
```

And i imported it in my file 1:

```
data (){
    return {
        users:[]
    }
},

methods: {
    getUsers : function() {

    this.users = apiService.get("/Users");
    }
}
```

Finally, i called the function and my users Array in the same file 1 like that :

```
<button @click= "getUsers"> Click here to get users </button>

<div> {{users}} </div>
```

BUT : when i click...
[that what happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PivMh.png)

To explain you a litte, my users Array contain a non-understable "Object Promise", but my function works bcs as you can see in the console.log the Arrays appears.

So, someone can explain me how can i do to display my differents users in my users Array instead of "Object Promise" ? and what is this "object Promise" ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `get` function is Promise because the function is `async` function. That's why you're getting Promise object.
So you should use `async/await` when you call `apiService.get()` function.

```
methods: {
    getUsers : async function() {
        this.users = await apiService.get("/Users");
    }
}
```

Also if you want to show the users, you can do sth like this:

```
<button @click= "getUsers"> Click here to get users </button>

<div
  v-for="(item, index) in users"
  :key="index"
>
  {{ `Name: ${item.name}, Address: ${item.address}` }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so muuuuuch !! <3

Comment: No problem. You can upvote the correct answer for other community members. :)